# Calling function displays the output  <function hello at 0x0000000002CD2198>

Tags: python, function

I'm having an issue with python and need some help. When calling any function it no longer displays the output but instead `<function hello at 0x0000000002CD2198>` (hello is function name). I've reinstalled Python but the problem remains. It was fine the other day and started to occur seemingly without reason.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 8):

You need to *call* your function, you are printing just the function object itself:

```
>>> def hello():
...    return "Hello World"
...
>>> print hello()
Hello World
>>> print hello
<function hello at 0x1062ce7d0>
```

Note the difference between the the `hello` and `hello()` lines.

Answer (score 4):

call function as `func()`, functions are called with parenthesis in front of them:

```
>>> def hello(): 
        print "goodbye" 

>>> hello()    #use parenthesis after function name
goodbye

>>> hello         #you're doing this
<function hello at 0x946572c>

>>>hello.__str__()
'<function hello at 0x946572c>'
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you called `hello` by

```
hello
```

Try `hello()` instead

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness:

Even if `hello` was actually being called, it could of course be that `hello()` simply returns another function.

Consider this:

```
    def hello():
        """Returns a function to greet someone.
        """
        def greet(name):
            return "Hello %s" % name
        # Notice we're not calling `greet`, so we're returning the actual
        # function object, not its return value
        return greet

    greeting_func = hello()

    print greeting_func
    # <function greet at 0xb739c224> 
    msg = greeting_func("World")

    print msg
    # Hello World
```